# c# regex required

Tags: c#, regex

I am very poor in regex,  i would appreciate if someone helps in this regex

Regex should match :-  any text before first forward-slash else full text, and then text that is not inside braces

```
HELLO/anything/blah/bhah ---------> should return HELLO 
{HELLO}/anything/blah/bhah -------> should not return any thing
ABC/blah/blah---------------------> should return ABC
ABC-------------------------------> should return ABC
```

Comment: -1 for not showing that effort was made

Comment: @above i have already told iam very poor in regex, and for me it seems like giant logic to make.

Comment: regex is stupid-easy.  just take an hour to study the basics:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^\w+` should work where:

`^` - match beginning of input

`\w` - match any word character (0-9a-zA-Z plus a few punctuation)

`+` - match one or more

If you'd prefer to be explicit:

`^[0-9a-zA-Z]+`

`[0-9a-zA-Z]` means almost the same as `\w`

Comment: updated to fix a minor mistake

Comment: Thats actually not entirely correct, as the second line will not be matched correctly

Comment: Thanks @deiga, you were right, i should have ensured the regex started at the beginning

Comment: Remember to prefix with ^ to not match anything for the second case

Comment: I was about to down vote you until you added the `^`, you matched too much otherwise.

Comment: yeah, @deiga pointed that out and made me realize that issue

Comment: thanx it worked. i wasted hours for this. i was stuck in too many if this and if that...

Comment: Please accept if it helped. It helps you and me :)

Answer (score 0):

This simple regex matches the requirements as you stated them:

```
^[A-Z]*
```

Starting from the start of the string, it takes any uppercase letters until it meets a character not in the list, which means it stops at the `{` and `/` characters.

Comment: {HELLO}/anything/blah/bhah   ---> is returning  --> "" empty string(i expect it to return nothing), thanx for your help though. James Deville's answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for example:

```
var l = new string[] {
    "HELLO/anything/blah/bhah",
    "{HELLO}/anything/blah/bhah",
    "ABC/blah/blah",
    "ABC"
};

foreach (var s in l)
{
    Regex r = new Regex("^(?!{[^/]*})([^/]*)/?");
    Console.WriteLine(r.Match(s).Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: HELLO/anything/blah/bhah   ---> is returning  --> "HELLO/", thanx for your help though. James Deville's answer solved my problem

Comment: no it's not... did you copy paste the code as it is?